# Matrix multiplication computation

Tags: matrices

Any tips how to solve this?

$$
\left[ \begin{matrix}1 & 2 & 0 \\ -2 & -5 & 1 \\ 11&15&5 \end{matrix}\right] \times \mathbf{X} \times \left[ \begin{matrix} -4&5&1\\ -4&5&1 \\ -4&5&1\end{matrix}\right] =\left[ \begin{matrix}-12 & 15&3 0 \\ -24&-30&6 \\ -125&150&31  \end{matrix}\right]
$$

Comment: I think that edit may have removed the variable $X$ between those two LHS matrices?

Comment: No the edit is wrong there should be X between the 2 matrices

Comment: Yes the edit removed the X

Comment: Since the matrix to the right of $A$ has such a simple form, start by multiplying those two together.

Comment: Inverting the leftmost matrix might help.

Comment: Okey but the matrix after A is invertable so no solution?

Comment: @Arthur but there is a matrix that is invertable(The one after A) doesn't this mean no solution?

Comment: You're right. The left-hand side is not invertible and the right-hand side is. So no solutions.

Answer (score 1):

First instinct would be to multiply on the left and right by inverses to get $A$ on its own on the LHS. However the rightmost of these matrices is not invertible. But we can get 
$$
A \times \left[\begin{array}{ccc}-4 & 5 & 1\\-4 & 5 & 1\\-4 & 5 & 1 \end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 235 & 0 & -599 \\ -\frac{247}{2} & \frac{15}{2} & \frac{629}{2} \\ -\frac{343}{2} & \frac{15}{2} & \frac{761}{2}\end{array}\right]
$$

The system of equations for the components of $A$ is over-determined. This means that, letting
$$
A = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\ b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\ c_1 & c_2 & c_3\end{array}\right]
$$
we see (for instance) that this requires
$$
-4 (a_1 + a_2 + a_3) = 235 \\
\implies a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = -\frac{235}{4}
$$
but 
$$
5 (a_1 + a_2 + a_3) = 0 \\
\implies a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = 0
$$
which is clearly contradictory. So no solution exists.

Comment: And if the left was inivertable and the right was ok same as the matrix after = sign then it does not have solution?

Comment: In the matrix equation $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{C}$, if both $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are invertible, then we can just compute $X = \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{B}^{-1}$

Comment: Also Michael if we find $A^t$ of the second and the one after the equation and put them in 3x6 matrix and try to find the first one to be E the result on the right will be AX=NewMatrix and here we also get contradiction so no solution

Comment: Yes agree if A B can be inverted

Comment: Also do we have to save the order when we multiply matrixes?After finding the inverse

Comment: Of course, order is always important. If $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{C}$ then $\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}^{-1} = \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{B}^{-1}$. Applying the inverses on the wrong sides would not remove either $\mathbf{A}$ or $\mathbf{B}$ from the left hand side.

Comment: And last question if we had the A matrix with same rows and the matrix C with the same rows but B is ok what do we say

Comment: By `same rows' you mean one row repeated three times? If this is the case then since $\mathbf{A}$ would not be invertible, there would be no solution. There is only a solution if both $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are invertible. There is no such restriction on $\mathbf{C}$.